# How to re-create initial migration on the same .cs file

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

As common in EF Code First I've generated an "Initial Create" migration file where is located an outdated model of my db (I'm developing the app so the model is still changing). Now I have a "new model" defined in my code and instead of creating a new migration for that I just want to update the already existing file, because it still is the initial create migration.

I've tried using this without any luck

> Update-database -targetmigration $initialcreate

It returns

```
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.
```

I also tried this one, but it's always creating a new .cs file

> Add-Migration InitialCreate

I'll appreaciate your help

Comment: From what I understand , you don't want to create a new migration? If then you can try to delete the whole migration folder and do `Enable-Migration` again. You will see that the new `InitialCreate` file will have your model .However , this seems not appropriate as Code-First Migrations are meant to have a listing of different periods of migrations containing what you have added in your Model( be it class or property). You can choose to rollback to previous migration(which you already did with `-targetmigration`) so it is very flexible.

Comment: Also, you can try `Update-Database -TargetMigration:0` if the above doesn't work.

Comment: @ShawnYan Yes, I don't want to create a new migration because my model is still changing, so there are no "migrations" yet.

Comment: Ok I understand, so can you rollback to initial create?

Comment: @ShawnYan Yes I can, my idea is to keep just one "Initial Migrate" file until the DB design process ends

Comment: Ok glad your problem is solved :-)

Comment: Generally, when I am in the early stages of development I use and initializer that will just keep changing my database when the model changes. If I need test data I use an initializer seed(). Then when things start to stabilize I switch to migrations. I frequently delete my initial migration during this phase and then rerun add-migration InitialSnapshot -IgnoreChanges.

Answer (score 14):

Here you can see how I solved this.

*Be careful with this approach because in my scenario I'm still in development phase so I do not need to keep the database nor the data.*

**If you want to overwrite the current "InitialCreate" file and re-generate the DB, follow these steps:**

1) Run in Package Manager Console:

> Add-Migration InitialCreate -force

2) Delete the physical database (use SSMS, T-SQL or your prefered)

3) Run in Package Manager Console:

> Update-Database -TargetMigration:0 | update-database -force | update-database -force

**If you do not care about the current "InitialCreate" file itself, want to create a new one and re-generate the DB, follow these steps:**

1) Delete current "InitialCreate" .cs file

3) Run in Package Manager Console:

> Add-Migration InitialCreate

4) Delete the physical database (use SSMS, T-SQL or your prefered)

4) Run in Package Manager Console:

> Update-Database -TargetMigration:0 | update-database -force | update-database -force

Answer (score 10):

My Project is Solved.
Run in Package Manager Console:

1. Drop-Database
2. Remove-Migration
3. Add-Migration InitialCreate
4. update-database

Comment: On my case, I had to right click to solution, and select Clean Solution menu item for some reason.

Comment: @Dinch Thanks, saved my hour. I think what you did is necessary, otherwise in my case too, most of the suggestions here did not work.

Comment: @Dinch also I have to run remove migration twice.

Comment: I would suggest updating answer and adding  @Dinch suggestion to Clean Solution  (after performing Remove-Migration).  I guess Visual studio is caching information in .pdb files or somewhere else.  with addition of Clean Solution,  this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the initial migration files from the 'Migrations' folder and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your database by writing `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console instead.