# Combine migrations in MVC 5 Code First Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Very quick question.

I work on a MVC 5 Code First project and I do a lot of small changes in the DB models. Sometimes the changes overwrite previous ones.
Is it safe to `update-database -targermigration InitialCreate` and then remove all migrations (except initial) and `add-migration cumulative` ?
I expect expert opinions like **Yes** or **No**.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you haven't deployed your database to production yet, and you're still doing development, I wouldn't create any migrations yet. When you're done with the model, and ready to push to production, then yes, create an initial migration.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I update DB regularly for development purpose so DB changes. The project still runs on iisexpress. Thank you.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari As I understand, keep making small migrations and combine them before deployment. Am I right?

Comment: While you're doing development you can enable automatic migrations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx. Then when you're ready to deploy you re-create the InitialMigration.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari If you wish you can explain in short your best practice (and receive `+1`) ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be interesting to know other people's practices on this, but I'll add what I would do. (Disclaimer: I haven't done this myself in a long time)

A bit of context first. Code migrations are snippets of code telling the database how to update itself after you make a change in your model classes. Since you're doing development and you haven't pushed code to production, there's no point in doing migrations because there is no production database that needs taking care of. For now, if needed, you could simply delete your local DB and rebuild it from scratch every time you make a change. But this is time consuming.

But there is a better way: **automatic migrations**. Every time you make a change and call `Update-Database`, EF will (behind the scenes) create a migration and update the database for you.

1. Run `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations`.
2. Every time you make a model change, run `Update-Database`.

Note that in some changes will still require that you add a migration manually, as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx#Adding%20a%20Code%20Based%20Migration).

Now, this is obviously not suited for a production environment, [for a variety of reasons](https://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/).

So when you're done building the MVP version of your app, I would just delete the local DB, and override the initial migration as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704211/1623249).

1. Delete `InitialCreate.cs` (or the entire `Migrations` folder for that matter...)
2. Run `Add-Migration InitialCreate`
3. Delete the local database.
4. Run `Update-Database -Force`.